# What is SO using akamaihd.net for?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I just had to enable http://akamaihd.net/ for JavaScript on SO.

1. Was that safe?
2. What does it do for SO?
3. Will we get notified when SO uses new services so we know that you've not been taken over?

Comment: It's a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Comment: I just saw all CSS styling disappear for stackoverflow, starting about 15 minutes ago.  On View Source, the CSS link appeared to have changed to that server for 5-10 minutes.  My company blocks access to that server because it's "Personal Network Storage and Backup".  After refreshing pages for a few minutes, the CSS link tag in HTML now appears to be set to a path on cdn.sstatic.net, and it's not blocked for me; CSS styling now works again.

Comment: +1, this CDN is blocked at my work as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We were running a short test to see how Akamai performed compared to our normal CDN. So it was used to serve all static content on Stack Overflow - CSS, JavaScript, some images...

The test has now completed. Please return to your regularly-scheduled browsing.

(It is still active on [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) if you care to test and report problems though)

Comment: Can you take into consideration that some workplaces block that CDN due to video streaming services which make use of it?

Comment: Yeah... That's definitely something we'd have to consider before attempting a full deployment. Hopefully, there's a way around that.

Comment: I trust you noted the issues about blocking for some people.  It might be worth putting up a blog entry somewhere so we know that it was intentional not the result of hijacking.  I wasn't dreadfully worried (I enabled it before I posted my question!), but I do keep an eye on what's allowed to set cookies and run JavaScript, and I doubt I'm alone.

Comment: @Shog9: thanks, they won't even fix their PAC script to correctly discriminate between IPs that start with `3.` and subdomains which start with `3.`, so getting akamaihd unblocked would take an act of Congress.

Comment: Fair point, @Jonathan - next time we run a test, we'll try to make sure folks have a visible indication so they know where to go. If we decide to switch CDNs permanently, a blog post would certainly be warranted.