# Unstyled content on all Stack Overflow pages

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, design

Currently, whenever I open a new page containing any Stack Overflow content: main page, tagged questions, an individual question, user profile, anything, all content is completely unstyled, as if all CSS was removed.  I did View Source, and this style sheet reference is present.

> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
>   href="http://sstatic-a.akamaihd.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=fca729ed9ab4">

Navigating to that site, I can see that my company blocks content from that site.

Meta Stack Overflow is not affected; the CSS link here in Meta appears to be locally hosted.

> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
>   href="/content/stackoverflowmeta/all.css?v=36683b668064">

I've seen [this behavior before on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172409/what-is-so-using-akamaihd-net-for).  Is this another test?  How often are these tests?  Will the tests stop at some point?

**EDIT**

All CSS content appears to have been restored on Stack Overflow.  The CSS link has changed to

> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
>   href="http://turbo-test.cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=fca729ed9ab4">

Comment: The tests will **never stop**. MUAHAHA

Comment: Your company firewall blocks Akamai CDN resources?!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Not the firewall; it's WebSense.  Reason: This Websense category is filtered: Streaming Media.

Comment: WebSense *is* a firewall.,

Answer (score 7):

We are testing several CDN candidates at the moment in 10 minute intervals - we'll be stable again in a bit.  We want to deliver the content to you guys as fast as possible, so we're seeing what options perform best.

Comment: For some reason chat(on all three sites) isn't working for me (Connection timed out). Is this related to the CDN issue?

Comment: @Manishearth - nope, chat is undergoing no tests and is working normally on our side.

Comment: Ah well. Anyway, it stopped breaking -- probably something screwy on my end.