# The site-specific chat rooms have lost their site's favicons. Could they be restored?

Tags: bug, chat, favicon

Over the last few hours, the SE chat rooms appear to have reverted to the SE favicon ([image: https://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico]). For example, the [Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) chat room, which is linked to [Super User](https://superuser.com/) previously had SU's icon ([image: http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico]). This seems to have affected all Chat.SE rooms.

Is this a planned change? Or is this a bug introduced in a recent update? If so, could it be fixed?

---

Comparing the source, the line `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico?v=abcdef">` was missing previously. I'm not sure why. Looks like most browsers just grabbed the domain favicon (https://chat.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico) instead.

One other person could reproduce, while several others could not. It worked through a proxy, but not on two different computers, or a phone on a different internet connection. Some browsers (IE7, IE10, Opera) did not display a favicon at all.

Comment: FF20, IE8, Chrome 26, all do this. Opera shows a blank icon for some reason.

Comment: No repro here... so at the very least, it's probably not a planned change. :)

Comment: possible dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176304/unstyled-content-on-all-stack-overflow-page

Comment: @Manishearth I'm not too sure this is a dupe: while the tests mentioned in that answer may be related, [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176304/unstyled-content-on-all-stack-overflow-pages#comment529397_176306) specifically states chat should not be affected. Also, that's for the SO main page, not the SE chat. And it's for missing CSS, which isn't the issue here. And the problem there was an inability to access the linked file, while here the relevant `<link>` tag was missing entirely (I checked.). Still probably related, but the questions are clearly different.

Comment: It works now, anyway, so I don't really care what you do with this question. But I don't think it is a dupe (though that answer might explain it).

Comment: @Bob: That's the chat site itself. The chat icons are on CDN, IIRC.

Comment: @Manishearth Yes, they use the same favicon URL. But the chat source itself was missing that `<link>` tag I quoted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now, so, it probably just a temporary glitch.